# How to compare EC50s from fitted logistic functions with a t-test

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, t-test, prediction

I used JMP to fit logistic dose-response curves to assay data, and used these curves to predict EC50 values. The EC50s are concentrations for different plant compounds. I want to find out statistically if one plant compound has a lower or higher EC50 than another. I tested the compounds on several annual weeds and plant pathogens. JMP gives EC50 estimates, SE values, and confidence intervals related to these EC50 estimates. I have discussed this issue with a statistician at my University and also found a document online, both sources suggest I use the equations:

tstatistic= (EC50A - EC50B)/SE for difference between EC50s

SE difference btwn means= sqrt[ SE(EC50A)^2 + SE(EC50B)^2]

I think the SE difference between means equation is fine, even if sample sizes are not equal. But I am not sure.

If the sample sizes are equal then, from what my sources tell me:

df= (sample size producing both logistic curves) - (# of parameters in both curves) - (2)

So I have two main questions:

1. Is this methodology correct for doing a t-test with EC50 values? If not, how should I modify it?
2. If variances or sample sizes are not equal, how does this change calculating SE for difference between EC50s, and the tcritical degrees of freedom?